# How can you check if an input (email) field contains a special character using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I'm using the following code but it doesn't seem to work. I would like to throw an error if a user fails to enter an "@" symbol in an input field. Please bear with me. Thanks

My following code is:

```
var emailaddressVal = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val().split('@').slice(1)[0].trim();

if(emailaddressVal .match(/@/) !== null) {
    alert('An @ symbol was not entered');
}
```

Comment: All you need is `$("input[name='emailAddress']").val(); ` before checking with the regex.

Comment: @Pointy Do you have an example?

Comment: ?? Just drop everything after `.val()` in the first line of code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're doing a lot more work than you need to. Your `split()` call searches for the bad character, so you could stop there and see if the string was split or not. But that's not a very clear way of expressing your intent.

If you're looking for a specific character, you don't need a regex.

Why not just

```
if ( $("input[name='emailAddress']").val().indexOf('@') > -1 ) { 
    /* we found an '@' character; handle as you like */ 
} else {
    /* NOT FOUND, handle as appropriate */
    alert("Missing a required '@' character");
}
```

`indexOf` returns a non-negative value if it finds the string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thanks! How can I show an error when the field Does Not contain @?

Comment: I added an `else` clause that kicks in if the @ sign is not found. The first line of code tests if `indexOf` returned a position (0 or a positive number, the position of the '@' in the emailAddress field). If it's not found, `indexOf` returns -1, so the test fails, and execution falls into the `else` block where you handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with `indexOf`? It does not always have to be so complicated :

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
```

```js
document.getElementById('test').onkeyup = function() {
    if (this.value.indexOf('@')>-1) {
        alert('error');
    }        
}
```

or jQuery

```js
$("#test").on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('@')>-1) {
        alert('error');
    }        
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/t49xdx56/**